# How to add offset after sortBy in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I add offset after using `sortBy` in laravel? Please see my code below.

**Controller**

```
$order_type = ($dir == 'asc') ? 'sortBy' : 'sortByDesc';

$inventories = $inventories->get()->$order_type(function($inventory) {
   $item_status = [
     '0'  => 'I',
     '1'  => 'D',
     '2' => 'HI',
     '3' => 'HR',
     '4' => 'A',
     '5' => 'DS'
   ];

   return $item_status[$inventory->receive_item->inspection_status];
});

$inventories = $inventories->offset($start)->limit($limit);
```

**Error I get**

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method offset does not exist.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @lagbox Laravel v5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection's do not have an `offset` or `limit` method. You can use `slice` and `take`:

```
$inventories->slice($start)->take($limit)
```

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `slice`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-slice)

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `take`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-take)

Comment: I got an error using `skip`.  `Method skip does not exist.`

Comment: Works well. Didn't know `slice` exists :)